# How to best route multiple slack interactions through a single URL?

Tags: python, flask, slack

I'm developing a Slack Bot using Slack's Interactive Components to request information through dialogs. All Interactive Components (buttons and dialogs) must pass through a single URL. What is the best way to parse the POST request sent by slack and take the necessary action I have defined elsewhere?

Right now I have two functions that accomplish this task together. First I parse the POST request to get an identifier that serves as a key of a dict of possible function calls.

Then I use the key to index into a dict of functions that I have predefined to determine what function should be called. A returned value of True indicates that the function has a return value that must be returned to Slack.

```
def get_action(request):
    data = form_json = json.loads(request.form["payload"])
    key = None

    if data['type'] == 'interactive_message':
        key = data['actions'][0]['value']

    elif data['type'] == 'dialog_submission':
        key = data['callback_id']

    elif data['type'] == 'dialog_cancellation':
        key = 'cancellation_' + data['callback_id']

    return key, data


def get_func(key):
    options = {
        'issue_dialog': (False, dialog.issue),
        'announcement_dialog': (False, dialog.announcement),
        'event_dialog': (False, dialog.event),
        'travel_dialog': (False, dialog.travel), 
        'good_news_dialog': (False, dialog.good_news), 
        'ask_dialog': (False, dialog.ask),
        'pulse_dialog': (False, dialog.pulse), 
        'check_in_dialog': (False, dialog.check_in), 
        'test_dialog': (False, dialog.test),
        'pulse_message': (False, message.pulse), 
        'cancel': (True, message.cancel), 
        'issue_submission': (False, submit.issue.delay),
        'announcement_submission': (False, submit.announcement.delay), 
        'event_submission': (True,  submit.event),
        'travel_submission': (True,  submit.travel), 
        'good_news_submission': (False, submit.good_news.delay),
        'check_in_submission': (False, submit.check_in.delay), 
        'ask_submission': (False, submit.ask),
        'pulse_submission': (True,  submit.pulse), 
        'pulse_history': (False, submit.pulse_history.delay),
        'test_submission': (False, submit.test.delay), 
        'cancellation_pulse_submission': (False, submit.cancel_pulse)
        }
    ret = options[key]
    return ret
```

The dictionary of functions I have right now is getting out of hand as I add more functions. What sort of organization should I use for parsing and retrieving the correct function?